# Run command on logout, *before* encrypted home is unmounted

Tags: encryption, logout

I'm running 14.04 LTS with an encrypted home directory.  I've got a service ([profile-sync-daemon](https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon)) needs access to files in my home directory when it starts and stops, so needs to start after the encryped files are mounted and stop before they're unmounted.  Starting the service at the right time can be achieved running `service psd start` from Startup Applications.  Where can I put the `service psd stop` command?

I've tried using `session-cleanup-script` in `/etc/lightdm.conf`, but that seems to run too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The well-known Upstart event emitted when the desktop is shutting down is "`desktop-end`" (and there is also a corresponding "`desktop-start`"). Hence, something like the following should work:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/upstart/
cat <<EOT|tee ~/.config/upstart/psd.conf
start on desktop-start
stop on desktop-end

exec psd

EOT
```

Note: you'll need to change that `exec` line to the command to start the `psd` daemon. Alternatively, you could create a job without an `exec` stanza and instead call commands to start and stop the daemon like this:

```
post-start exec command-to-start-psd
pre-stop exec command-to-stop-psd
```

I've never used psd, but your question seems to suggest it is running as root? If so, I think you should investigate if it is possible to run an instance of the daemon as your user (safer and will make it easier to create the Upstart job).

For more details on well-known upstart events:

- man upstart-events
  (or http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific)

See also:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#exec
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#script
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user

Comment: Thanks, [here's the script I ended up using](https://gist.github.com/marxjohnson/ddee2a13f3e0d70a7ea0)

PSD does have to run as root, so I've added a line to /etc/sudoers to allow my user to run it without a password.